# how to validate email on input type text field in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I want to validate email address on text field i.e. `<input type='text'/>` fields. I know in html5 there is a separate field for `email` i.e `<input type='email'/>`. But due to some reasons I can't / don't want to use that tag. Also in HTML 5 there there is default validation messages. But I am using some thing like below to show custom validation messages:

```
oninvalid='this.setCustomValidity("please enter your first name")' oninput='setCustomValidity("")'
```

this code is working fine for my `required` text fields. I want to validate my email address in same way with custom messages like: you have not included @ sign or you have not included domain name etc. How can I do this with similar pattern for showing email validation with custom HTML 5 messages.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13798313/set-custom-html5-required-field-validation-message

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validate email address textbox using JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7635533/validate-email-address-textbox-using-javascript)

Comment: @ceejayoz there they are using alert box to show it is invalidate. I want HTML 5 validation messages that comes near the field like a tool tip.

Comment: @Teomanshipahi from the link you have mentioned, from there only I have added oninvalidate and oninput event attributes on my text field.