# How to validate an E-mail field in a multi step form with JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, validation

I made a multi step form with html/css/js.
Now in the second step when I click Next I need the E-mail field to be validated. The "email" type attribute in html doesn't work and IDK why. I also need the Phone Number to be optional.
PLEASE HELP !

Here is the code for HTML, CSS and JS:

```js
var currentTab = 0; // Current tab is set to be the first tab (0)
showTab(currentTab); // Display the current tab

function showTab(n) {
  // This function will display the specified tab of the form ...
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  x[n].style.display = "block";
  // ... and fix the Previous/Next buttons:
  if (n == 0) {
    document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "none";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "inline";
  }
  if (n == (x.length - 1)) {
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Submit";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Next";
  }
  // ... and run a function that displays the correct step indicator:
  fixStepIndicator(n)
}

function nextPrev(n) {
  // This function will figure out which tab to display
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  // Exit the function if any field in the current tab is invalid:
  if (n == 1 && !validateForm()) return false;
  // Hide the current tab:
  x[currentTab].style.display = "none";
  // Increase or decrease the current tab by 1:
  currentTab = currentTab + n;
  // if you have reached the end of the form... :
  if (currentTab >= x.length) {
    //...the form gets submitted:
    document.getElementById("regForm").submit();
    return false;
  }
  // Otherwise, display the correct tab:
  showTab(currentTab);
}

function validateForm() {
  // This function deals with validation of the form fields
  var x, y, i, valid = true;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("input");
  // A loop that checks every input field in the current tab:
  for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    // If a field is empty...
    if (y[i].value == "") {
      // add an "invalid" class to the field:
      y[i].className += " invalid";
      // and set the current valid status to false:
      valid = false;
    }
  }
  // If the valid status is true, mark the step as finished and valid:
  if (valid) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("step")[currentTab].className += " finish";
  }
  return valid; // return the valid status
}

function fixStepIndicator(n) {
  // This function removes the "active" class of all steps...
  var i, x = document.getElementsByClassName("step");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].className = x[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  //... and adds the "active" class to the current step:
  x[n].className += " active";
}
```

```css
/* Style the form */

@media (max-width: 981px) {
  .first-h {
    display: none;
  }
  .first-p {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 571px) {
  #regForm {
    height: fit-content !important;
    width: fit-content !important;
  }
  .name-h {
    font-size: 26px !important;
    margin-bottom: 40px !important;
  }
  #prevBtn {
    color: rgb(202, 202, 202) !important;
    font-size: 18px !important;
    padding: 5px 15px !important;
    font-weight: 100 !important;
    border: 1px solid #f05b5b9f !important;
  }
  #nextBtn {
    font-size: 18px !important;
    padding: 5px 35px !important;
    margin-top: 40px !important;
    font-weight: 100 !important;
    border: 1px solid #f55858 !important;
  }
  input::placeholder {
    font-size: 12px;
  }
}

#regForm {
  background-color: rgb(54, 54, 54);
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: 150px !important;
  padding: 40px;
  width: 70%;
  height: auto;
  min-width: 300px;
}

.first-h {
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px auto 35px auto;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}

.name-h {
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px auto 35px auto;
  font-size: 26px;
  color: #f55858 !important;
}

.first-p {
  background-color: #f558581a;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto 30px auto;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 15px 5px;
  border-top: 1px solid #f55858;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f55858;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}


/* Style the input fields */

input {
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #3f3f3f;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: Raleway;
  border: 1px solid #424242;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
}

input::placeholder {
  color: #e2e2e298;
}

input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

textarea {
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #3f3f3f;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: Raleway;
  border: 1px solid #424242;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
}

textarea::placeholder {
  color: #e2e2e298;
}

textarea:focus {
  outline: none;
}


/* Mark input boxes that gets an error on validation: */

input.invalid {
  background-color: #a04e4e85;
}


/* Hide all steps by default: */

.tab {
  display: none;
}


/* Make circles that indicate the steps of the form: */

.step {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbbbbb;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0.5;
}


/* Mark the active step: */

.step.active {
  opacity: 1;
}


/* Mark the steps that are finished and valid: */

.step.finish {
  background-color: #f55858;
}

#nextBtn {
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-weight: 700 !important;
  border: 3px solid #f55858;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  background-color: rgb(44, 44, 44);
  box-shadow: 0px 20px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1;
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: 0.25px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
}

#nextBtn:hover {
  background-color: #1a1919d0;
  border: 3px solid #ecececb9;
  color: #ecececb9;
}

#nextBtn:focus {
  outline: none;
  border: 3px dotted #ececec56;
}

#prevBtn {
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-weight: 700 !important;
  border: 3px solid #f05b5b9f;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  background-color: rgb(44, 44, 44);
  box-shadow: 0px 20px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1;
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: 0.25px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
}

#prevBtn:hover {
  background-color: #1a1919d0;
  border: 3px solid #ececec56;
  color: #ecececb9;
}

#prevBtn:focus {
  outline: none;
  border: 3px dotted #ececec56;
}
```

```html
<form id="regForm" method="POST" action="https://formspree.io/f/xnqopyzd">

  <h1 class="animate__animated animate__zoomIn first-h">HI THERE</h1>
  <p class="animate__animated animate__zoomIn first-p">AC.IE would love to hear from you. Introduce yourself, let us know what your project is about and we can support your innovative idea or collaborate as partners. </p>

  <!-- One "tab" for each step in the form: -->
  <div class="animate__animated animate__zoomIn tab">
    <h1 class="name-h">Let's start with your name:</h1>
    <p><input required name="First Name" placeholder="Type your name" oninput="this.className = ''"></p>
    <p><input required name="Last Name" placeholder="Type your last name" oninput="this.className = ''"></p>
  </div>

  <div class="animate__animated animate__fadeIn tab">
    <h1 class="animate__animated animate__backInLeft  name-h">and your contact...</h1>
    <p><input required type="email" name="E-mail" placeholder="Enter your E-mail" oninput="this.className = ''"></p>
    <p><input class="optional" type="tel" name="Phone Number" placeholder="Enter your Phone Number (Optional)" oninput="this.className = ''"></p>
  </div>

  <div class="animate__animated animate__fadeIn tab">
    <h1 class="animate__animated animate__backInLeft  name-h">Organization. Tell us the company/org name and also in what position you're in.</h1>
    <p><input name="work" placeholder="Type 'none' to skip" oninput="this.className = ''"></p>
  </div>

  <div class="animate__animated animate__fadeIn tab">
    <h1 class="animate__animated animate__backInLeft  name-h">Where do you live ?</h1>
    <p><input name="country" placeholder="Enter your city & country" oninput="this.className = ''"></p>
  </div>

  <div class="animate__animated animate__fadeIn tab">
    <h1 class="animate__animated animate__backInLeft  name-h">Enter your Social Media</h1>
    <p><input name="social" placeholder="@instagram, @twitter, @facebook etc.." oninput="this.className = ''"></p>
  </div>

  <div class="animate__animated animate__fadeIn tab">
    <h1 class="animate__animated animate__backInLeft  name-h">Tell us about yourself and also why is your idea socially innovative?</h1>
    <p><textarea name="idea" type="text" placeholder="Type your message here. Talk a little bit about yourself and your idea.." oninput="this.className = ''"></textarea></p>
  </div>

  <div style="overflow:auto;">
    <div style="float:right;">
      <button type="button" class="animate__animated animate__fadeIn" id="prevBtn" onclick="nextPrev(-1)">Previous</button>
      <button type="button" class="animate__animated animate__zoomIn" id="nextBtn" onclick="nextPrev(1)">Next</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Circles which indicates the steps of the form: -->
  <div style="text-align:center;margin-top:140px;">
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
  </div>

</form>
```

You can run the code and see it.
Please help me. Please help me. Please help me. Please help me. Please help me.  !

Comment: Hi , email validation will get called when you click on `type="submit"` .Instead [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7635612/10606400) answer is alternative try it might help .

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the *type* attribute for the email to become "Email".
And remove the required attribute for the phone input.